# phpBB permissions issue

Tags: phpbb

I'm in the process of installing phpBB, it says I need certain permissions for a few directories (image). I tried changing the permissions via FTP clients but it won't change. FileZilla even gave me this:

```
Command:    SITE CHMOD 777 cache
Response:   500 'SITE CHMOD 777
cache': command not understood
```

How do I change these permissions? I'm running Windows Server. Any help?

[image: phpBB install]

Comment: How are you accessing the server? Do you have some sort of control panel? Do you have remote desktop access?

Comment: @PaulMorriss: Yeah I have remote desktop - the server is Windows based and has Plesk control panel. I enabled 'Additional Modify/Edit Permissions' on Plesk and it seems to have worked (even though my FTP clients say otherwise, and still don't seem to be able to change the permissions. However, phpBB said they were ok ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

777 are Unix/Linux type permissions, and a Windows Server won't know how to interpret them as it doesn't have the same concepts of user/group/other, which is what each of the digits is for. As you say in the comment the way to do it is to use the control panel, or an FTP client which understands windows permissions.